# How to create reciprocal and adverbial sentence in german

Tags: adverb

I want to create some reciprocal sentence, but I'm not sure, whether their german equivalent is fine. I think *himself* and *by himself* have only one german translation that could be *selbst*. In my following examples I would like to prefer using *selb* and *-einander*. Maybe some translation of them could be simply *gegenseitig* but I especially would like to find out the usage of *by/ -self* *-selves*, *one another*, *each other*.

> (1) one another --> The three sisters are devoted to one another. (Die drei Schwestern sind einander gewidmet.[possible: miteinander?])
>
> (2) each other --> The children had a fight and started to hit each
>   other. (Die Kinder hatten einen Streit und begannen einander zu schlagen.)
>
> (3) myself -->I'm not sure if I'll type my paper myself. (Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich meine Arbeit selber schreiben[possible: selbst?].)
>
> (4) by himself--> He’s lived by himself since his wife died. (Er lebt selbst seit dem Tod seiner Frau.)

Comment: There is no reciprocity in (3) nor (4).

Comment: @chirlu yes you're right, i must find a proper title for my question

Answer (score 3):

(1)
»Widmen« is very wrong here. The verb »widmen« means: to dedicate. You can not dedicate a person to another person.
Possible translations are:

> Die drei Schwestern sind einander ergeben.
>   Die drei Schwestern sind einander zugetan.
>   Die drei Schwestern sind einander treu.
>   Die drei Schwestern hängen aneinander.

(2)

> Die Kinder hatten eine Streit und begannen einander zu schlagen.
>   Die Kinder hatten eine Streit und begannen sich gegenseitig zu schlagen.

(3)

> Ich bin (mir) nicht sicher, ob ich meine Arbeit selbst schreibe.
>   Ich bin (mir) nicht sicher, ob ich meine Arbeit selber schreibe.

(4)

> Er lebt allein nachdem/seitdem seine Frau gestorben war.

Comment: Using _einander_ there is a hidden dative case, right? To 3: using _mir_ is optional?

Comment: @user1474062: Einander: No. The verb makes the case. Jemande**m** ergeben sein, jemande**m** zugetan sein, jemande**m** treu sein, an jemande**m** hängen. But: Jemande**n** schlagen. So in all sentences in (1) *einander* by accident is in dative case. But in the 1st sentence in (2) **einander** is in accusative case because »schlagen« generates accusative case. About »*mir*«: Jes it is optional, but it chaneges the meaning a little bit.

Comment: How about "of each other. e.g. they are something of each other." voneinander possible?

Comment: @Bergmann: Please write full sentences. (Your question ... no verb!) I didn't understand what you wanted to ask.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast what could be translation of "...of each other. e.g. they are the hyponyms of each other." _voneinander_ could be right translation for _of each other_ ?

Comment: Sorry, @Bergmann, I still don't understand what you want to know.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast i just would like to translate this sentence: " they are the hyponyms of each other." in german. But i'm having difficulties translating _ the hyponyms of each other_ actually translating "...of each other" part.

Comment: If sememe *A* is a hyponym of sememe *B*, then *B* can not be a hyponym of *A* (because it is it's hyperonym, which is the opposite of a hyponym). Example: »Chicken« is a hyponym of »bird«, so »bird« can't be a hyponym of »chicken«, because »bird« is a hyperonym of »chichen«. (Every chicken is a bird. But not every bird is a chicken.) You can translate »they are the hyponyms of each other« as »sie sind Unterbegriffe voneinander«. This sentence is grammatical correct, but semantic it is nonsense.